# Get the time duration/ time elapsed - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am creating an app where I have to measure the time duration of the match in hh:mm. I want this timer to start when the view is loaded and for it to end when the stop button is pressed. How can I do this?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new variable in your header

```
NSDate *startTime;
```

In `viewDidLoad`, assign the current time

```
startTime = [NSDate date];
```

When the stop button is pressed, you can grab the elapsed seconds as such:

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = -[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
int hours = seconds / 3600;
int minutes = (seconds - hours * 3600) / 60;
NSString *timeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", hours, minutes];
```

Comment: The return type of `timeIntervalSinceNow` is `NSTimeInterval`, not `float`. And the casts for `hours` and `minutes` aren't needed.

Comment: Ahh, been muddling in C# for too long.